# How to I solve an AssertionError?

Tags: python

I want my function to assert that:
• Every element in the compressed stream is the proper type (string or
tuple)
• Every string is at least one character long
• Every tuple has exactly two elements, both of which are positive integers
• The “offset” (the first element in the tuple) does not point back any further
than the start of the uncompressed string.

I have this code, but it gives me an AssertionError on the third to the last line (assert i[0] <= length_2)

```
res = ""
    for i in meter:
            assert type(i) == str or type(i) == tuple
            if type(i) == str:
                length = len(i)
                assert length >= 1
                res += i
            elif type(i) == tuple:
                assert len(i) == 2 and i[0] > 0 and i[1] > 0
                print(i[0])
                length_2 = len(res)
                assert i[0] <= length_2
                res+= res[-i[0]: - i[0] + i[1]]
        return res
```

Comment: Where is `res` initially defined?

Comment: No, you're incrementing `res` in line 6. Where is it defined prior to that?

Comment: my mistake. Edited

Comment: So if the type is a tuple, then `res` has a length of 0, but in previous assertion you're checking that `i[0] > 0`. Do you see the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues in this snippet. The main error comes from the fact that if `i` is a tuple, then `res` is an empty string with a length of 0.

In the assertion prior to the one that fails you're checking that `i[0] > 0` but then in the failing assertion you're trying to assert that `i[0] <= len(res)` (I replaced `length_2` with its value `len(res)` to make it more clear). So you're asserting that `i[0]` is simultaneously greater than 0 and less than or equal to zero.

Obviously, this is a contradiction.

Also, do not use assertions in the final code. It is acceptable during testing and in unit tests, but in the final code you should be checking with if-statements and raising specific errors when required.

Finally, do not check object type with `type()`, the correct way is to use `isinstance()`.

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks.